# Maths question Geometry: Soccer field

Tags: geometry

Question Four:                  (This contributes to a KAP A; CAJ)

The diagram below shows the measurements of a soccer field layout. On the actual field the white lines are 4cm wide. Assume the field length is 100m long and 90m wide.  The part circle near the goal is a third of a circle with the same radius as the centre circle.

Find the area of the paint lines on the soccer field.

Will these calculations give sufficient information for obtaining how much paint will be needed to paint all of these lines?  If not, why not?  What factors would need to be considered when painting the lines in terms of how much paint will be used.

Describe any assumptions you have made when making these calculations.  State any limitations to the calculations.  That is, have you left out calculating any of the lines.  If so how does this affect your answer.
[image]

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: im just confused what to do

Comment: compute the length of the lines you have to draw and multiply the total length by $4\,cm$ to get an approximation of the amount of paint needed.

Comment: so how would you dO THAT

Comment: By computing the length of the segments and circular arcs involved, how else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are told that the outer border is $100 \times 90$ meters.  That gives a perimeter of $380$ meters.  The area of the paint making up the outer border is then $380 \cdot 0.04$ square meters.  Go through all the other lines on the field, add up the lengths, and multiply by $0.04$ to get the paint area.  To get the volume, you need to assume something about the thickness.  I see dimensions for all the lines except the small boxes behind the goal.